# Who Will Win the Game

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

The question is based on this [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20180128174428/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55980.html).

A player can choose any number (regardless of whether or not it was chosen during a previous turn) in the inclusive range between $L$ and $R$.

The game ends when the running sum of chosen numbers (i.e., sum of all numbers chosen by *both* players) is greater than or equal to $K$, and the last player to take their turn wins.

For given $L,R,K$, which player will win?

```
Min Value = K- R*[(K/R)]
Min Value>=L first one will win
```

Comment: Can one choose real numbers, or do they have to be integers?

Comment: only Integer.. I have updated the answer with my Approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially a *subtraction game*. Rather than counting up, let's start at $K$ and count down. The first person to make the sum drop to $0$ (or below) wins.

If $K > L+R$, then take out as many multiples of $L+R$ as possible to produce a value $K'$ in the range $(1,L+R)$.

- If $K' \in (1,R)$, then the next player wins.
- If $K' \in (R+1, L+R)$, then the next player loses.

If a player is in a winning position, then in general they respond to the other player's move by choosing a value that makes both moves add up to $L+R$. To put it another way, the players would like to make a move that leaves a sum $K'$ (as described above) within the range $(R+1,L+R)$.

---

Example: Suppose $(L,R) = (4,7)$, and $K=25$. We calculate $K'=25-2(11)=3 \in (1,4)$, so the first player to move wins. The winning moves are $4,5$, and $6$.

Comment: `L=1 , R=10` and `K=11` , so `K' = 0` Wining Move 0,1... But Second player is always wining

Comment: @ytfutyuy Perhaps I could have written it more clearly, but the point is to make sure that $K'$ is in the range $(1,L+R)$. So in your example, $K'=11$ because it is already in that range.